# Solution to sync files on 2 computers in 2 remote locations

Tags: sync, online-backup

My friend runs 2 osteopath clinics and works between the 2 locations with another osteopath (they rotate which days they work in each clinic). A laptop stays at each clinic, and until recently were simply using a USB stick to backup all their electronic files. When either went to the other clinic they would manually "sync" their files across the 2 computers (using the USB stick).

After the London riots they realised they need to be smarter (one clinic was ransacked, laptop stolen).

When they first asked me I suggested an online backup service like Mozy, but now I understand they don't just want online backups, but to also use the service to keep the files on both laptops in sync so they can access the same file in either location.

What services/software are available? I'm not sure Mozy will work. Has anyone else setup something similar?

#### Additional Info:

It needs to be idiot-proof (both users are technophobes), and considering the confidentiality of a lot of the data - security is paramount. Last night's comments are raising that encryption is a must (I just assumed that solutions like Mozy would be encrypted and secure).

They're *not* looking for free - although "enterprise" is probably out of their league.

Comment: Are the files that will be synced in use at the same time?

Comment: There are programs that will backup your files automatically.  The real concern is that if the files contain Personal Identification Information or Personal Medicial Information a good majority of those solutions cannot be used.  What ever solution you do use, the information must be encrypted, otherwise you will be visiting your friend in jail if the files are leaked.

Comment: The files being synced won't be used at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

Since the dropbox + truecrypt ideas got a lot of grief... you probably should give us some additional insight on what *you* consider acceptable under your company's policies & local regulations.

If you already have a central server, you can always make use of file replication tools like [synctoy](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=15155) or [unison](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/) to automatically keep files in sync by scheduling a task to sync every 10 or 30 minutes (more or less as you see fit)

Synctoy is nice & simple... but is limited to UNC paths & local drives... so something like that you'd probably have to have a vpn tunnel in place and network-share access to a remote server.

Unison is really designed for *nix systems but does also have a windows implementation that works quite well.  You can use UNC paths & local drive letters... but you have the advantage of also using sftp/scp to a remote server to transfer the files securely.  It also works better with large files as it has the ability to only transmit the changes to a file rather than the entire file on any minor change.  It can also be a bit more confusing than synctoy.

Comment: I don't think they're that advanced with a formal policy. They're just 2 self-employed osteopaths. But of course they have to comply with the UK Data Protection Act. (This means actually I need to find a solution that isn't hosted in the US, unless we don't use an  online service - http://www.ico.gov.uk/for_organisations/data_protection/the_guide/principle_8.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for persevering. There's no remote server present - just 1 laptop in each clinic (connected on plain old ADSL, dynamic IP addresses). I am thinking something along these lines though (whether synctoy/unison or something else) rather than an online backup might be the best option here.

Answer (score 0):

1 word... [DropBox](http://www.dropbox.com/)

The desktop application will keep your files in sync... and it also has versioning support... as well as being freeeeeeeeeee.

Comment: For doctors?  I'm not sure what kind of laws the UK has governing their data, but they have to worry about complying with those if that data they're syncing falls under the governance of any laws regarding client/patient info and confidentiality.  Dropbox almost certainly doesn't fit.

Comment: Privacy and dropbox are never used in same sentence.  They haveh ad issues in the past

Comment: I would hope there isn't a solution like this that exists for this problem except for encrypted remote storage.

Comment: Sure... lots of hate from everyone... but no better suggestions.  DropBox is fine as long as you remember it's "cloud storage" and should be treated as such.  Encrypt anything you are worried about security.  On the flip side... a true-crypt volume thrown in a drop box is a quick & simple way to securely have data in 2 places... without a thumb-drive.

Comment: @TheCompWiz - There are laws unique to the UK dealing with personal information.  DropBox is an American company, subject to our laws, which means a great deal of concerns even if the information is encrypted.  I suggested Amazon only because I do not agree with DropBox EUA.

Comment: @TheCompWiz: That's because many of us don't have to deal in data bound with things like HIPAA (or non-American equivalents), and I'm not familiar enough with the laws to make any real recommendations, but know enough to not flippantly recommend cobbling together TrueCrypt + Dropbox.  While it might *work*, is it *defensible*?  If the OP is doing any work for his friend in a professional capacity, he might be on the hook for some stiff penalties if he's wrong.

Comment: I'm sure that there are enterprises offering secure, private, and certified cloud services for health care providers, I just don't know who they are or even what laws everyone involved is bound by in the UK.

Comment: I consider answers as a "brainstorming" forum rather than "here's the end-all-be-all answer to everything".  Dropbox may work in many situations where security is not as paramount.  The OP did not specify any requirements for security or that he would be sharing sensitive/important data.  I was only commenting on the vast number of -1's over my answer.  It's not the ideal answer in this situation... I'll admit... but it is by no means an invalid or bad answer.

Answer (score 0):

if data-files are NOT "binaries"

*and*

same file can be changes on both sides at the same time

*and*

you have to have 2-side sync

you must to use any **usable for you** own or hosted *VCS solution, I think